# Delete or smart pointer failure

Tags: qt, taglib

I'm using Taglib and writing the cover art to the mp3.  The following code here works:

```
 bool MediaHelper::AddCoverArt(const QString &media, const QString &image_file)
 {
    TagLib::MPEG::File mpeg(media.toStdString().c_str());
    TagLib::ID3v2::Tag *id3v2Tag = mpeg.ID3v2Tag(true);
    TagLib::ID3v2::AttachedPictureFrame *frame = new TagLib::ID3v2::AttachedPictureFrame;
    frame->setMimeType("image/jpeg");
    frame->setPicture(image.data());
    id3v2Tag->addFrame(frame);
    mpeg.save();
    delete frame;
    return true;
}
```

but once i leave the function the app crashes with read access violation

I then tried it with a QScopedPointer:

```
 bool MediaHelper::AddCoverArt(const QString &media, const QString &image_file)
 {  
    TagLib::ID3v2::Tag *id3v2Tag = mpeg.ID3v2Tag(true);
    QScopedPointer<TagLib::ID3v2::AttachedPictureFrame> frame(new TagLib::ID3v2::AttachedPictureFrame);
    frame->setMimeType("image/jpeg");
    frame->setPicture(image.data());
    id3v2Tag->addFrame(frame.data());
    mpeg.save();    
    return true;
}
```

But same thing happens when I leave the function.  I'm kinda stumped because if I dont take care of deleting frame then I will be creating a big problem for myself.  If anyone can give me some insight.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the TagLib API documentation:

> void TagLib::ID3v2::Tag::addFrame(Frame * frame)
>
> Add a frame to the tag. At this point the tag takes ownership of the frame
>   and will handle freeing its memory.

The tag takes care of deleting the frame. If you delete the frame yourself as well, you end up with a double-delete, and if the tag accesses the frame before deleting it in its destructor, that would result in an access violation as well.

Comment: Thanks I looked at the docs description but not the functions. Thank you for clearing it up for me